# Assigning Value to a column in a dataframe based on a different column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv converted from a registry edit .reg file. Dataframe like below:

```
Path,Key,Type,Value,date_time
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\1,Key,hex(0),0000000180000600,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\1,KeyLength,dword,00000008,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\1,Rw,hex(0),ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\1,RwLength,dword,000000e8,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\1,RwMask,hex(0),ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\2,Key,hex(0),0000000080000600,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\2,KeyLength,dword,00000008,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\2,Rw,hex(0),ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\2,RwLength,dword,000000e8,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\NsiMigrationRoot\7\2,RwMask,hex(0),ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp,@,NONE,Paint.Picture,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp,Content Type,NONE,image/bmp,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp,PerceivedType,NONE,image,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp\OpenWithList,NONE,NONE,NONE,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp\OpenWithList\MSPaint.exe,@,NONE,,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp\OpenWithProgids,Paint.Picture,NONE,,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp\PersistentHandler,@,NONE,{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb},1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp\ShellNew,ItemName,hex(2),40002500730079007300740065006d0072006f006f00740025005c00730079007300740065006d00330032005c006d0073007000610069006e0074002e006500780065002c002d00350039003400310034000000,1487463163.916084
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp\ShellNew,NullFile,NONE,,1487463163.916084
```

I have a function that I call right before I export to csv to convert types hex(7) and hex(2) to ascii characters like below:

```
def fn(foo):
    if "NONE" in foo:
        return foo
    else:
        try:
            x = re.sub(' |\n|\t|00', '', foo)
            return "".join(binascii.unhexlify(x).decode())
        except:
            binascii.Error
```

I have validated that this function works.

My issue is that when I convert like below:

```
df['Value'] = df[df['Type'].str.contains('hex\\(2\\)')]['Value'].apply(lambda x: fn("".join(x)))
```

This converts my type hex(2) to ascii, but removes the remaining values of other types.

I also attempted something like below:

```
df[df['Type'].str.contains('hex\\(2\\)')]['Value'] = df[df['Type'].str.contains('hex\\(2\\)')]['Value'].apply(lambda x: fn("".join(x)))
```

How can i reference just the hex(7) and hex(2) values and replace their values only in my dataframe and leave the remaining values alone? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [229]: df.loc[df.Type.str.contains('hex\((?:2|7)\)'), 'Value'] = \
              df.loc[df.Type.str.contains('hex\((?:2|7)\)'), 'Value'].map(fn)

In [230]: df
Out[230]:
                                       Path            Key    Type                                    Value     date_time
0   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgr...            Key  hex(0)                         0000000180000600  1.487463e+09
1   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgr...      KeyLength   dword                                 00000008  1.487463e+09
2   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgr...             Rw  hex(0)  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff...  1.487463e+09
3   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgr...       RwLength   dword                                 000000e8  1.487463e+09
4   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgr...         RwMask  hex(0)  ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff...  1.487463e+09
5   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgr...            Key  hex(0)                         0000000080000600  1.487463e+09
6   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgr...      KeyLength   dword                                 00000008  1.487463e+09
..                                      ...            ...     ...                                      ...           ...
12  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\...  PerceivedType    NONE                                    image  1.487463e+09
13  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\...           NONE    NONE                                     NONE  1.487463e+09
14  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\...              @    NONE                                      NaN  1.487463e+09
15  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\...  Paint.Picture    NONE                                      NaN  1.487463e+09
16  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\...              @    NONE   {098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}  1.487463e+09
17  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\...       ItemName  hex(2)  @%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe,-...  1.487463e+09
18  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\...       NullFile    NONE                                      NaN  1.487463e+09

[19 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: @johnnyb, try this: `df.loc[df.Type.str.contains('^(?:hex|hex\([27]{1}\))$')]`

Comment: You referenced my fn() function might not be working as expected, was there a reason why?

Comment: @johnnyb, sorry, i was wrong. I've removed that comment